# With LibGit2Sharp, should the Status command show changes that are committed, but not yet pushed?

Tags: c#, libgit2sharp

I have a repository in which I currently have two files.  I made a change to one file, and committed the change, but haven't pushed it yet.  When I run 'git status' from a command line, I get the following:

```
On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

This is as expected.

I have some code in C# to get the status of the repository, as shown here:

```
using (Repository repo = new Repository(localRepoFolder))
{
    RepositoryStatus status = repo.RetrieveStatus();
}
```

When I step through the code and do a dump of the *status* variable, I get the below:

```
status
+0 ~0 -0 | +0 ~0 -0 | i0
Added: Count = 0
DebuggerDisplay: "+0 ~0 -0 | +0 ~0 -0 | i0"
Ignored: Count = 0
IsDirty: false
Missing: Count = 0
Modified: Count = 0
Removed: Count = 0
RenamedInIndex: Count = 0
RenamedInWorkDir: Count = 0
Staged: Count = 0
Unaltered: Count = 0
Untracked: Count = 0
added: Count = 0
dispatcher: Count = 9
ignored: Count = 0
isDirty: false
missing: Count = 0
modified: Count = 0
removed: Count = 0
renamedInIndex: Count = 0
renamedInWorkDir: Count = 0
staged: Count = 0
statusEntries: Count = 0
unaltered: Count = 0
untracked: Count = 0
Results View: Expanding the Results View will enumerate the IEnumerable
```

It doesn't seem to show the difference between the local and remote like the command line does.  How do I get it to show the same as the command line status command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Status` gives you just the actual status of the repository - the differences between `HEAD` and the index, joined on the differences between the index and the working directory.  It does not include any of the additional metadata like ahead/behind counts.

If you want to know how your branch relates to its tracking branch, then you can look at the branch's `TrackingDetails`.  eg:

```
Console.WriteLine("Your branch is ahead of '{0}' by {1} commits and behind by {2} commits.",
    branch.TrackingBranch.CanonicalName,
    branch.TrackingDetails.AheadBy,
    branch.TrackingDetails.BehindBy);
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and code!  I'm more familiar with Subversion and TFS, so Git is taking a little time to get used to.